# Using a long spear one-handed

Tags: weapons, runequest-glorantha

Page 219 of *Runequest: Roleplaying in Glorantha* (2018) says:

> [A lance] can also be used as a one-handed spear if the adventurer has the necessary STR and DEX to use a long spear one-handed.

Where are the rules for using long spears or two-handed weapons in general with one hand? What STR and DEX are required? The weapon table on page 209 shows that a short spear can be used with one or two hands, but that long spears must be wielded two-handed, as does the item description on page 211.